# C# command to truncate all tables in T-SQL or SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to execute this query in C#

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'DELETE FROM ?'
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all
```

When I run it in SQL Server Management Studio, it works. But in C# code the query is not working.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection truncateconnection = new SqlConnection(connection);
    truncateconnection.Open();

    string sql3 = @"EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
                    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'DELETE FROM ?'
                    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all'";
    SqlCommand cmd_truncate = new SqlCommand(sql3, truncateconnection);

    cmd_truncate.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Working");

    truncateconnection.Close();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: there is no error..

Comment: If you want resolve your errors then provide use your dummy script. after that some one find the solution for you otherwise there is no any clue to execute the over statement.

Comment: @ShahzadKhan thats my script...

Comment: try add semicolon to the end of each command

Comment: ok i'll try @Squirrel

Comment: still not working @Squirrel

Comment: So just to be clear, it prints out "Working" but the tables are not altered in the why you expect . . . is that correct?  If so, does the first NOCHECK statement work . . . or is only the CHECK CHECK part failing?

Comment: how to execute the script to my c#???????? there is no error happen i put try catch. but when i execute it to the ssms its working..

Comment: @Frank I dont know what happen. i run to my script to the ssms its working the data is truncated, while in my button c# when i click it it's not truncated..

Comment: Did you run SQL Profiler to see if any commands are reaching the server from your C# application?

Comment: Weezy's comment is a good one, ask your DB Admin what the sever sees.  But you DO get the MessageBox . . . so you get to that line of code . . . correct?  Some other thoughts, ExecuteNonQuery() has a return value . . . what value is returned? . . . are any rows updated, additionally try making each EXEC in a different SqlCommand() and check the return value for each.  I'd explore those directions.

Comment: there is no row updated....

Comment: Two other ideas came to me last night:  1. Since you haven't shown us how this is called, I am wondering if some higher level of software is eating an exception.  If this is a possibility, wrap these calls in a try/catch so you can catch any see errors.  2. SSMS sets all kinds of defaults as can a connection string.  It would be nice to see your connection string to see if for instance you've set a database which might influence the Store Procedure.  Question: so the result of all three calls is zero, or you just don't see changes in your database?

Comment: i dont see any changes in my database. but if i script it to my ssms all my data truncated.